# zooming, dragging an image causing image loading delay

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I have an image that I can do zooming, moving around. and a custom ImageView class is handling the functionalities. my problem is whenever I do something on the image, zooming or dragging, i see gray areas at the beginning and then it looks ok. something wrong with loading the image.

code:

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

Comment: Clearly post the image, your expectations and your codes.

Comment: the code is here:   https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java